# Remove the menu button from a theme

Tags: javascript, html, css, themes, jekyll

Can anyone please tell me how to completely remove the menu button from this theme: https://github.com/vvalchev/creative-theme-jekyll-new

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the button completely.
It's this part:

```html
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```